# Unable to access form data inside ajax loaded data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a dynamic ajax loaded form that looks like the following:

```
<form id="ProtocolForm">
<input id="name_major" type="text" value="some value">
<input id="name_minor" type="text" value="some value">
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Protocol">
</form>
```

In the main page from which the ajax content is loaded, I have the following function:

```
$(document).on( "submit", "#ProtocolForm", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
alert('submit intercepted:' + $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

My problem is that I can't seem to access the actual form data from inside this function. The function is called appropriately, however both $( this ).serialize() and $("ProtocolForm").serialize() appear to be blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The inputs have no `name` attribute... That's why `.serialize()` catches nothing.

Comment: Oh geez, that was ridiculously stupid of me. Thanks!

Comment: That's not "stupid"... You did well to ask. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to dynamic content. You used delegation correctly.

But `.serialize()` relies on `name` attributes to collect a form data... Just add them.

;)